# Ordenar uma matriz (array) de double com base na coluna escolhida

Tags: delphi, classificação

Eu tenho uma matriz multidimensional no Delphi com 3 linhas e 2 colunas, eu queria uma forma de ordenar (sort) ela com base em uma coluna, segue o exemplo:

```
procedure;
var
Matriz: array of array of Double;
begin

  SetLength(Matriz,3,2);

  Matriz[1,1]:= 1;
  Matriz[2,1]:= 2;
  Matriz[3,1]:= 3;
  Matriz[1,2]:= 3;
  Matriz[2,2]:= 2;
  Matriz[3,2]:= 1;

end;
```

Minha saída seria essa caso eu ordene ela pela segunda coluna em ordem decrescente:

```
  Matriz[1,1]:= 3;
  Matriz[2,1]:= 2;
  Matriz[3,1]:= 1;
  Matriz[1,2]:= 1;
  Matriz[2,2]:= 2;
  Matriz[3,2]:= 3;
```

Pensei que Delphi tinha algo como sort(Matriz,2), mas em termos de trabalhar com matriz sempre tenho que fazer um rotina, existe alguma forma de fazer isso mais simples (nem manualmente consegui)?Uma biblioteca numérica?

Comment: Qual versão do delphi?

Comment: @Caputo XE5, existe funções para isso? Ou você está pensando em um TList<T> genérica?

Comment: Que algoritmo de ordenação você precisa? pode ser quicksort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando o algoritmo de ordenação QuickSort, modifiquei apenas para aceitar a matriz ao invés do array:

Primeiro defina o tipo:

```
TMatrixType = array of array of Double;
```

O Algoritmo recebe 4 parâmetros, a matriz, o índice mínimo da linha, o índice máximo da linha e a coluna que você deseja ordenar:

```
procedure QuickSortDoubleMatrix(var Matrix: TMatrixType; iLo, iHi: Integer; Column: Integer);
var
  Lo, Hi: Integer;
  T, Pivot: Double;
begin
  Lo := iLo;
  Hi := iHi;
  Pivot := Matrix[(Lo + Hi) div 2][Column];
  repeat
    while Matrix[Lo][Column] < Pivot do Inc(Lo) ;
    while Matrix[Hi][Column] > Pivot do Dec(Hi) ;
    if Lo <= Hi then
    begin
      T := Matrix[Lo][Column];
      Matrix[Lo][Column] := Matrix[Hi][Column];
      Matrix[Hi][Column] := T;
      Inc(Lo);
      Dec(Hi);
    end;
  until Lo > Hi;
  if Hi > iLo then
    QuickSortDoubleMatrix(Matrix, iLo, Hi, Column);
  if Lo < iHi then
    QuickSortDoubleMatrix(Matrix, Lo, iHi, Column);
end;
```

Crie uma aplicação console:

```
var
  Matriz: TMatrixType;
  Linhas, Colunas, I,J: Integer;

begin
  SetLength(Matriz,6,2);

  Matriz[0,0]:= 1;
  Matriz[1,0]:= 2;
  Matriz[2,0]:= 3;
  Matriz[0,1]:= 3;
  Matriz[1,1]:= 2;
  Matriz[2,1]:= 1;

  Matriz[3,0]:= 4;
  Matriz[4,0]:= 5;
  Matriz[5,0]:= 6;
  Matriz[3,1]:= 6;
  Matriz[4,1]:= 5;
  Matriz[5,1]:= 4;

  Linhas:= 5;
  Colunas:= 1;

  for J:= 0 to Colunas do
    for I:= 0 to Linhas do
      Writeln(format('Matriz[%d, %d] = %.2f', [I+1,J+1, Matriz[I,J]]));

  QuickSortDoubleMatrix(Matriz, 0, Linhas, Colunas);

  Writeln('');
  Writeln('');
  for J:= 0 to Colunas do
    for I:= 0 to Linhas do
      Writeln(format('Matriz[%d, %d] = %.2f', [I+1,J+1, Matriz[I,J]]));
  Readln;
end.
```

Output:

```
Matriz[1, 1] = 1,00
Matriz[2, 1] = 2,00
Matriz[3, 1] = 3,00
Matriz[4, 1] = 4,00
Matriz[5, 1] = 5,00
Matriz[6, 1] = 6,00
Matriz[1, 2] = 3,00
Matriz[2, 2] = 2,00
Matriz[3, 2] = 1,00
Matriz[4, 2] = 6,00
Matriz[5, 2] = 5,00
Matriz[6, 2] = 4,00


Matriz[1, 1] = 1,00
Matriz[2, 1] = 2,00
Matriz[3, 1] = 3,00
Matriz[4, 1] = 4,00
Matriz[5, 1] = 5,00
Matriz[6, 1] = 6,00
Matriz[1, 2] = 1,00
Matriz[2, 2] = 2,00
Matriz[3, 2] = 3,00
Matriz[4, 2] = 4,00
Matriz[5, 2] = 5,00
Matriz[6, 2] = 6,00
```

Comment: cara muito obrigado!